# Amazon s3 redirect rule with dynamic path value

Tags: url, redirect, amazon-s3, path, hosting

I have a S3 bucket and I am writing static web site hosting rules.
My s3 is configured like this:

```
bucket
ㄴ test
  ㄴ dynamic-value
    ㄴ us
      ㄴ en
        ㄴ index.html
    ㄴ default
      ㄴ index.html
```

this is my url:
http://www.example.com/test/dynamic-value/us/en/index.html

the "dynamic-value" is dynamic like A, B...

And I want to redirect when response is 404:
http://www.example.com/test/dynamic-value/default/index.html

I want to change /us/en to /default my path, and the root path is dynamic when the page is 404 error.

Before:

```
http://www.example.com/test/A/us/en/index.html
http://www.example.com/test/B/us/en/index.html
```

After:

```
http://www.example.com/test/A/default/index.html
http://www.example.com/test/B/default/index.html
```

I tried next rule, but it is not working. 
the relative path(means "../../" in my code) works just "../../"(string).

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>www.example.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>../../default/index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

please help!!! :'(